# Is there a way we can make the Java Language Server to skip checking `node_modules` files while starting up in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, redhat, language-server-protocol

Since I am having a couple of angular projects within the same workspace along with Spring Projects, the Java Language Server that runs for providing Java support to VSCode takes an enormous time (~10 mins) to run through all the contents of the workspace which includes `node_modules`.

Is there a way/setting that I can use to tell it to skip certain folders/files so that I can speed up the initialization of the Java Language Server? Especially contents of `node_modules`?

[image]

Comment: The best way is to talk to its developers directly, https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues

Answer (score 0):

As of v0.66.0 of the extension, there is the `java.project.resourceFilters` setting. As it defaults to ["node_modules",".git"], your problem should be solved by using a current version of the `redhat.java` extension.

If you'd like to exclude more folders, you can add them in your `settings.json`.

[#1460](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1460) is the matching issue for this question.

--
But: this does not work for me atm. [See #1655](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1655), my setting seems to be ignored, I'll try to resolve this with the devs and update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm still acting the same problem.